# Chromecast HTML page on various sized displays

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, chromecast, google-cast

Developing an android application with cast ability. Need to cast a basic [HTML recipe page](http://www.basilapps.com/recipe/index1.html) on the display screen.

I am a newbie to HTML/CSS/JS world, so having a basic query:

During casting, we don't know in advance the display size. It can be a 32" LED TV or 46" or a small 18" display.

So is there a way to adjust HTML page size according to the screen display size? Or do we need to use "BootStrap" to develop responsive web-page for the same?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical size of your TV screen is irrelevant. As for window size, it is 1280x720 but it is best to query for the window size within your JavaScript so if in future things change, you can adapt accordingly. Again, the physical size of TV screen doesn't have any effect.